# SSL certificate requirements for an HTTPS website

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet which is designed to auto-populate a form on a site.

The site is here: [http://www.bniconnectglobal.com](https://www.bniconnectglobal.com/web/secure/home)

Now the site has a SSL certificate that 'enables the green bar' (sorry for my ignorance).

So now I have a few questions:

1. What is the difference between a 'green bar' https site and a none green bar https site. Is it just the level of checks performed?
2. Now I understand that for my script to work on this site I need to have a SSL certificate, but will my script work on this site with a basic SSL certificate (e.g. [123-SSL](https://www.123-reg.co.uk/ssl-certificates/123-ssl-certificates.shtml)), or will I need a full SSL that activates the 'green bar'?

**EDIT**

Clarity (as my original title pointing out it was a bookmarklet was edited.)

If I have a bookmarklet's script hosted on **my domain** - there will definately be NO problem with me having a basic SSL cert and bniconnectglobal.com having a full security certificate (extended certificate).

For those of you who haven't created a bookmarklet before it is simply a bookmark that appends a script to the current page using:

```
javascript:function addtopage(){var d=document,z=d.createElement('scr'+'ipt'),b=d.body,l=d.location;try{if(!b)throw(0);z.setAttribute('src',"//mydomain.com/myscript.js");b.appendChild(z);}catch(e){alert('Please wait until the page has loaded.');}}addtopage();void(0)
```

**END EDIT**

1. If I use a relative URL (`//mydomain.com` instead of `https://mydomain.com`) am I going to run into any browser issues on old browsers?

The second one is my main question but if someone could answer all 3 that would be great!

Comment: Green bar = "extended validation"; indeed the only difference is that more checks are done at identity verification. 2 A normal cert is OK, I recommend http://startssl.com/

Comment: cheers - marked as useful comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) A green bar usually means that the CA used additional steps to verify the identity of the certificate bearer.

2) You do not need the green bar from a technical point of view. It is supposed to offer more trust, but is usually just a selling point for the CAs to charge you even more.

3) Not a problem, but ordinary certificates are usually not wildcard certificates (*.domain.com) Those are generally more expensive.

Comment: Have you ever tried this before? i.e.with my bookmarklet being from a different domain with a different level of security DEFINATELY won't cause problems - my question has been editted so the title does not make it 100% clear - have editted my question to reflect this - if you answer is still correct after my edit just say so here and I will mark as answered.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you just want to post data to a website that has SSL enabled?

Comment: NO - I want to dynamically add my script to bniconnectglobal.com - this script will then fill in a form on a certain page - that bit is easy - I just can't get my head around whether using a lower 'level' of security certificate for my certificate (hosted on my site) will stop my script from running on the page.

Comment: No, you don't have to care about the validation level of the security certificate. That is unless the other website requires client authentication based on certificates. But that is another topic.

Comment: Thanks - no that won't be a problem - once script has run it has done its job - thanks for the answers. +1 and marked as accepted.

Comment: Different browsers represent the Extended 'Green bar' certificates differently from the standard https certificates. There's a list with screenshots here: https://www.expeditedssl.com/pages/visual-security-browser-ssl-icons-and-design.html